# Using find with curl combination

Tags: curl, ftp, find, influxdb, nas

I use the code below to send data to my NAS. The directory being created ends with a period. I don't want a period at the end. How can I prevent this.
The dir on my NAS is now as follows:
Dir: InluxDB.
Subdir: (date) as 07-03-2022

```
TEMPDIR="/tmp"
DESTDIRNAS="/Backups/InfluxDB"
DATE="$(date +%d-%m-%Y)"
BACKUPDIR="/tmp/influxdb"

cd $BACKUPDIR

find -type f -exec curl -u "USER:PASSWORD" --ftp-create-dirs -T {} "ftp://192.168.1.20/$DESTDIRNAS"{} \;

#delete tmp folder
rm -rf $BACKUPDIR
```

Answer (score 0):

To make `find` output with full/absolute path use `find "$PWD" -type f`

Suggesting the `curl` command:

```
find "$PWD" -type f -exec curl -u "USER:PASSWORD" --ftp-create-dirs -T {} "ftp://192.168.1.20/$DESTDIRNAS"{} \;
```

As for getting last directory in `$BACKUPDIR`

```
basename "$BACKUPDIR"
```

Returns `influxdb`

```
dirname "$BACKUPDIR"
```

Return `/tmp`

Comment: Dudi Boy.  I dont need the full/absolute path. Only the last directory in de $BACKUPDIR i wil upload to the NAS

Comment: See my answer update.

Comment: please mark question as answered.thanks